# Not Connecting from my zimbra webmail

Tags: centos5, dkim, zimbra

I have configured `zimbra` webmail on `centos 5.5 64bit` server for e-mail authentication.

I have installed `DKIM` and `dk-filter` on it after installation to check authentication. I tried to open zimbra by ip or by name but it showing :

> "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

Now I want to correct it. Please help me figure where the problem is.

Comment: Did you try accessing the Zimbra web page before you implemented DKIM ? Or did you mean to say that Zimbra web page is not opening after installing DKIM ?

Comment: zimbra web page is not opening after DKIM installation.

Comment: you could check if the status of zimbra services by issuing the command "zmcontorl status" as zimbra user. This may show you if one of the services is not running.